# velocity calculation algorithm

Tags: math, geometry

This is probably a very stupid math question, but i can't seem to figure it out. What i have is a circle at point A that i can click on and drag the mouse oway from it. When the mouse is released - the release point B is considered a target point and the ball has to move in that direction. What i'm doing now is something like this:

```
velocityX = (b.x - a.x) / somenumber
velocityY = (b.y - a.y) / somenumber
```

This allows me to use different "shot" speeds the further away the mouse is released from the circle. But now i realised that i don't like this idea and instead i want to do it the following way:

- to have a minimum and maximum speed (pixels per animation frame)
- to select the speed from this interval prior to the shot
- to use the point B simply for easier targeting. The shot speed is preselected and it should't depend on how far the mouse is released

I know it should be dead simple, but how do i (knowing point A and B coordinates, min, max and selected velocity) set x and y velocities to the circle taking into account the direction of the shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just normalize the vector from the center of the circle to the point and then multiply by the speed you want. In any goodl vector library there is such a function, but just to clarify:

```
length=square_root((b.x - a.x)^2+(b.y - a.y)^2)
velocityX = (b.x - a.x) / length * speed
velocityY = (b.y - a.y) / length * speed
```

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two ways to do it.

lets say the angle from a to b is T. Then:

T is equal to atan((b.y-a.y)/(b.x-a.x))

knowing T you can calculate the x and y velocities:

Vx = cos(T)V
Vy = sin(T)V

That should work.

To make things quicker you could calculate cos(T) and sin(T) directly.

sin(T) gives the proportion y/h, where h is the length of the line between a and b.

We can calculate h using the Pythagorean theorem:

h = sqrt((b.y-a.y)^2 + (b.x-a.x)^2)

from this we can derive formulas for Vx and Vy

Vx = V * (b.x-a.x)/sqrt((b.y-a.y)^2 + (b.x-a.x)^2)

Vy = V * (b.x-a.x)/sqrt((b.y-a.y)^2 + (b.x-a.x)^2)

That's probably be faster, particularly if you have a built Pythagorean theorem function.