# Smooth moving from A to B

Tags: java, android, algorithm, math

I have a android game where I have to from time to time move camera (visible screen part) from point A to point B.

Obviously I could do it like that:

```
camera.setCenter(B.getX(), B.getY();
```

But it does not looks good, it simply jump immediately, and what I want to achieve is smooth movement from A to B. I can access onUpdate method which is loop updating certain game objects (so I can execute certain things in certain milliseconds)

I really can not figure out how to create such algorithm, to allow smooth movement between two points (Classifying I have no clue how to calculate what values should I add to the

```
camera.setCenter(camera.getX() + xValue, camera.getY() + yValue)
```

Because those values have to be calculated depends on what is distance between those two points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your game updates at 60 frames per second, and you want a transition to take two seconds, then it should take 120 frames to get there.

Thus, the amount it should move in any given update is `total/120`.

You can abstract this into a method that queues a movement, calculates the FPS and the amount to move each update, and calls `.setCenter` on its current position plus the update amount.  This is typically called [interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation).  To determine how far you need to move, its no more than the absolute value of `current - destination` (it doesn't matter which is in front of the other, so we just take the absolute value to ignore the sign. To be technical, [distance is a scalar whereas position is a vector](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/1dkin/u1l1b.cfm)).

So, to sum up in semi-code (I don't know the actual contracts for these functions):

```
//given these variables already have value
double fps, currentX, destinationX, currentY, destinationY, animationLength; //animation length in seconds
...
double xValue = Math.abs(currentX - destinationX);
double yValue = Math.abs(currentY - destinationY);
...
//on each update:
double amountToMoveX = xValue / (animationLength * fps);
double amountToMoveY = yValue / (animationLength * fps);
camera.setCenter(camera.getX() + amountToMoveX, camera.getY() + amountToMoveY)
```

Then you simply need to keep track of when to stop, and you should be good to go.

Whether or not you're using an engine that already has a means of doing this, I don't know.  But in terms of a pure algorithm, this seems the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

See the discussion from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456414/velocity-calculation-algorithm)

From the answer:

> length=square_root((b.x - a.x)^2+(b.y - a.y)^2)
>
> velocityX = (b.x - a.x) / length * speed
>
> velocityY = (b.y - a.y) / length * speed

Where xValue is velocityX and similarly for Y