# Shoot to the mouse direction

Tags: java, mouse, slick2d

### The problem:

I've got this "Shot" class. In the code, the target variables are the mouseX and mouseY.
So when i click the mouse button, my player class will create a new shot object.
But the shooting is inaccurate.
How can i calculate the correct dx and dy?

If i add the dx and dy to the "bullet's" x and y, the bullet will move to the mouse's direction.This is what i want. The mouse position is stored in targetX and targetY, when the object is created. This is the point what the oval wants to reach.

**Links:**

> [***The game (finished)***](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dhvf5vbqj25sgyw/game.jar)

**The code (from Shot.java):**

```
public class Shot extends Entity {
    private float targetX, targetY;

    public Shot(World world, float x, float y, int width, int height, Color color, float targetX, float targetY) {
        super(world, x, y, width, height, color);
        this.targetX = targetX;
        this.targetY = targetY;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g, Camera camera) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(x - camera.getX(), y - camera.getY(), width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(GameContainer gc, int delta) {
        float dx = targetX - x;
        float dy = targetY - y;

        x += dx * delta * .001f;
        y += dy * delta * .001f;
    }
}
```

**I tried this, but still not work:**

```
@Override
    public void update(GameContainer gc, int delta) {
        float length = (float) Math.sqrt((targetX - x) * (targetX - x) + (targetY - y) * (targetY - y));

        double dx = (targetX - x) / length * delta;
        double dy = (targetY - y) / length * delta;

        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }
```

**I did it! Here is my solution:** 
The problem was that, the target was the window's mouse position, and not the world's mouse position.

This is how i calculated the world's mouse positions:

```
float mouseWorldX = x + (mouseX - screen_width / 2); // x = player's x position
float mouseWorldY = y + (mouseY - screen_height / 2); // y = player's y position
```

Comment: Please add more information about how you want the dx and dy to work.  (Edit the quesiton).  Thanks

Comment: I try to add as much information as i can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is code from my game at the moment is used to move a unit to the mouse when the right mouse button is pressed:

```
length = Math.sqrt((target_X - player_X)*(target_X - player_X) + (target_Y - player_Y)*(target_Y - player_Y)); //calculates the distance between the two points

speed_X = (target_X - player_X) /length * player_Speed;

speed_Y = (target_Y - player_Y) /length * player_Speed;
```

This will move an object to the target in a line at a set speed.

Edit: this is the actual code right from my game

```
if(input.isMouseButtonDown(Input.MOUSE_RIGHT_BUTTON))
    {
        length = (float) Math.sqrt((player_waypoint_X - player_X)*(player_waypoint_X - player_X) + (player_waypoint_Y - player_Y)*(player_waypoint_Y - player_Y));
        velocityX = (float) (player_waypoint_X - player_X) /length * (float) PlayerStats.player.db_player_Speed;
        velocityY = (float) (player_waypoint_Y - player_Y) /length * (float) PlayerStats.player.db_player_Speed; 

        player_waypoint_X = input.getMouseX() - 2;
        player_waypoint_Y = input.getMouseY() - 2;

    }
```

For testing purposes the velocity's are defined in the init method along with length. Every time the right mouse is pressed the waypoints's X and Y are changed to the mouse location.

I learned this from this question
[velocity calculation algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456414/velocity-calculation-algorithm).

Comment: I tried it, i added the speed_x and speed_y to the ovals x and y, but its still the same.

Comment: I'm confused as to where the bullets are going in your example. At the start of the program the bullets go nicely to their target (I think). But then it seems the target randomly changes positions.

Comment: also could you put the shot class onto paste bin?

Comment: i noticed that too. Also i cant shoot downwards. (Shot.java has been added to the source list)

Comment: Though im still new to this, the problem might be caused by target_X and target_Y not being set properly. Maybe try adding an if statement for mouse clicked and set them to the mouse input and see if that changes anything. (just as an observation because I did get the guy to shoot downwards but it just randomly did so).

Comment: I noticed that if i not move the mouse, just the player, it will shoot into one specified position

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i tried random calculations, and one of them worked! Thanks again for your help

Answer (score -1):

in order to make the bullets not all change direction every shot, create an array list so that each bullet fired has its own x and y velocity